# Issue when filtering Iems by 2 conditions simultaneously in Asp.Net MVC 3 with LINQ To SQL data model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql

My data model consists of 4 tables: Item references Product, Shipping and User. I want to sort Items by Product fields: Category and Condition. In my app I use LINQ To SQL classes. Here is my code:

```
public ViewResult Content(string category, string condition, int page = 1)
{
    var Items = _itemsRepository.GetItems()
                .Where(i => category == null && condition == null || 
                (i.Product.Category != null && i.Product.Category == category) ||
                (i.Product.Condition != null && i.Product.Condition == condition))
                .OrderBy(i => i.ItemId)
                .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize)
                .Select(i => i);
     // return Items to the view
}
```

The problem also might be caused by routing, so here is the global.asax content:

```
        // without categories and conditions
        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Store/Content/Page{page}",
            new { controller = "Store", action = "Content", category = (string)null, condition = (string)null },
            new { page = @"\d+" });

        // with conditions
        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Store/Content/{condition}/Page{page}",
            new { controller = "Store", action = "Content", category = (string)null },
            new { page = @"\d+" });

        // with categories
        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Store/Content/{category}/Page{page}",
            new { controller = "Store", action = "Content", condition = (string)null },
            new { page = @"\d+" });

        // Default route
        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
```

If I put the route with categories above the rout with conditions it can sort by categories and vice versa. How can I sort by categories and conditions simultaneously? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how route with category could be selected - previous route will match same url

Comment: You're right. How should I write the routes? I tried also:  "Store/Content/{category}/{condition}/Page{page}". Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little optimized query (btw you are not sorting items by product properties - you are filtering them):

```
public ViewResult Content(string category, string condition, int page = 1)
{
    var Items = _itemsRepository.GetItems()
         .Where(i => ((category == null) || (i.Product.Category == category)) &&
                     ((condition == null) || (i.Product.Condition == condition)))
         .OrderBy(i => i.ItemId)
         .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
         .Take(PageSize)
         .Select(i => i);
    // return Items to the view
}
```

Regarding routing - as I stated in comment, your route for category cannot be executed. So, if both category and condition are optional, then you can pass one parameter with category and condition delimited by special character, or pass both as `category=foo&condition=bar`.

One more point - make sure your repository do not load items in memory, when you call `GetItems()`